# jquery autocomplete not returning value val()

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

source shoud be link /search/sam
my code should return the input value such as 'sam'
but returning null.

```
<script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
                autoFocus: true,
                minLength: 2,
                source: ["/search/" ,$(this).val()].join("")
            });
         });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken into thinking that `this` refers to the `$('#search')`, when it is not. It refers to `window` object, which, well, doesn't have a value and hence, `null`.

Do it this way:

```
$(function() {
    var elm = $("#search");
    elm.autocomplete({
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 2,
        source: ["/search/", elm.val()].join("")
    });
});
```

But still, don't know if it will work out, since the value will be `""` because there will be no value typed in by the user when the page loads.

You might want to take a look into ones which offer callbacks for populating the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use plus `(+)` sign istead of comma `(,)` . To make source link like :  `/search/sam`

Here is updated code :

```
<script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
                autoFocus: true,
                minLength: 2,
                source: ["/search/" +$(this).val()].join("")
            });
         });
</script>
```

Comment: check your console if there is any error. this must work